# What is the average rate of red blood cell production in humans?

Tags: red-blood-cell, cell-division

I was doing my biology research of the day and I came across the following question: How fast are red blood cells produced and, how do I calculate this?

I am currently using the following:
`Calculated estimated blood loss (cEBL) = (Predelivery HCT- postdelivery HCT) / predelivery HCT`.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. This is not simply an answer site, but instead a site that promotes self-learning with some expert help. Consequently, **questions that show little or no prior research effort** are off-topic on this site. Please [edit] your question and tell us exactly what you question is (reproduction of what exactly?), where you've looked for answers, what you *do* know about the topic, and where exactly you still have questions. Please take the [tour] and consult the [help] starting with [ask] for details.

Comment: One thing I suggest you look up is how RBC form (if that isn't what you are asking about, please remove that tag) — that should help you to phrase your question more clearly. I'm going to copy edit your post ("blood reproduction speed" and "blood reproduction rate" aren't clear and "how fast is the ... rate" is poor writing) to start to improve its clarity, but please check carefully to ensure I don't inadvertently change your intended meaning.

Comment: In addition, your equation is about blood loss not RBC generation — please add why you think that is relevant or edit the question so that that equation makes sense. Also note that all abbreviations must be defined before use — you should not assume we all know what HCT means.